# Using ArcPy to Spatial Join (points to points)

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

How can I reproduce the same result of this tool using ArcPy?

[image]

Here are the tables I want to join:

[image]

[image]

Here's the result im getting from ArcMap tool:

[image]

I wrote Python code to reproduce the same result:

```
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(gpsFC, hotspotFC, "test2.shp", join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
    join_type = "KEEP_COMMON",
    match_option="CLOSEST_GEODESIC",
    search_radius=0.001729,
    distance_field_name="distance")
```

but I'm not getting the same result, instead I'm getting this one:

[image]

Comment: Are both of your layers in lat/long? Do you have a selection on one of the layers?

Comment: Nope, one has a shape (point) and the other has lat/lon, as you can see in screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching gpsFC and hotspotFC, and setting distance = 0.03
and  match_option="CLOSEST".